# Bash script write without overwrite?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to test a `crontab` job by writing the date to a text file every minute as the following script shows:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> /home/SomeUserName/Desktop/date.txt
```

This almost accomplishes what I want but I don't want my script to overwrite the file in each iteration. So I used `>>` instead of `>` because I thought that it would only append to the file. Although, every time `crontab` executes the script I can only see one date.

Why is that so happening?

*I am using linux mint.*

Comment: are you sure you're executing the right file?

Comment: yes, when I execute it manually I get desired effect, but when I use crontab only latest date is saved.

Comment: You rightly expect that  you **should** be getting appends with `>>`, so please edit your Q to show the crontab entry that creates this problem. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post. The OP has attested that the shown script is working but failed to show the cronjob that isn't working. It's like showing a cup of good coffee while complaining of a bad milk.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that it should work as expected.

Created a script `/home/myuser/xd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> $HOME/date.txt
```

and a crontab (via `crontab -e`):

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  *   *   *     /home/myuser/xd.sh
```

Then I see the expected result:

```
$ cat date.txt 
Sa 16. Jul 02:02:01 CEST 2016
Sa 16. Jul 02:03:01 CEST 2016
Sa 16. Jul 02:04:01 CEST 2016
Sa 16. Jul 02:05:01 CEST 2016
Sa 16. Jul 02:06:01 CEST 2016
Sa 16. Jul 02:07:01 CEST 2016
```